Magento CSP csp_whitelist.xml but there are still violations remaining
I recently got my hands on magento_csp feature but I am not sure if I understood it correctly yet.
I have created a custom modul which purpose is like a centralized summary of csp entries.
app/code/Vendor/Modul/etc/csp_whitelist.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
  <policies>
    <policy id="font-src">
      <values>
        <value id="klarnacdn" type="host">*.klarnacdn.net</value>
        <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
        <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="data" type="host">data:</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="form-action">
      <values>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce" type="host">geostag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-geo" type="host">geo.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-stag" type="host">1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-api" type="host">1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-centinel" type="host">centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-centinelapi" type="host">centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="paypal" type="host">www.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-sandbox" type="host">www.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="adyen" type="host">*.adyen.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="frame-ancestors">
      <values>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="frame-src">
      <values>
        <value id="amc-demdex" type="host">fast.amc.demdex.net</value>
        <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
        <value id="doubleclick" type="host">bid.g.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="youtube" type="host">*.youtube.com</value>
        <value id="youtube-nocookie" type="host">*.youtube-nocookie.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce" type="host">geostag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-geo" type="host">geo.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-stag" type="host">1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-api" type="host">1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-centinel" type="host">centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-centinelapi" type="host">centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="paypal" type="host">www.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-sandbox" type="host">www.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="payflow" type="host">pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="vimeo" type="host">player.vimeo.com</value>
        <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
        <value id="adyen" type="host">*.adyen.com</value>
        <value id="klarna" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
        <value id="google-de" type="host">*.google.de</value>
        <value id="doubleclick-net" type="host">*.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="googlesyndication" type="host">*.googlesyndication.com</value>
        <value id="googletagservices" type="host">*.googletagservices.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="img-src">
      <values>
        <value id="adobedtm" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
        <value id="omtrdc" type="host">amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net</value>
        <value id="demdex" type="host">dpm.demdex.net</value>
        <value id="everesttech" type="host">cm.everesttech.net</value>
        <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
        <value id="magento-widgets" type="host">widgets.magentocommerce.com</value>
        <value id="data" type="host">data:</value>
        <value id="google-ads" type="host">www.googleadservices.com</value>
        <value id="google-analytics" type="host">www.google-analytics.com</value>
        <value id="doubleclick" type="host">googleads.g.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="google" type="host">www.google.com</value>
        <value id="bid-doubleclick" type="host">bid.g.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="analytics-google" type="host">analytics.google.com</value>
        <value id="googletagmanager" type="host">www.googletagmanager.com</value>
        <value id="ftcdn" type="host">*.ftcdn.net</value>
        <value id="behance" type="host">*.behance.net</value>
        <value id="t-paypal" type="host">t.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal" type="host">www.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-objects" type="host">www.paypalobjects.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-fpdbs" type="host">fpdbs.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-sandbox" type="host">fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
        <value id="youtube-img" type="host">i.ytimg.com</value>
        <value id="youtube" type="host">*.youtube.com</value>
        <value id="swagger" type="host">validator.swagger.io</value>
        <value id="adyen" type="host">*.adyen.com</value>
        <value id="unsplash" type="host">https://images.unsplash.com</value>
        <value id="klarna" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
        <value id="klarnaevt" type="host">*.klarnaevt.com</value>
        <value id="klarnacdn" type="host">*.klarnacdn.net</value>
        <value id="google-de" type="host">www.google.de</value>
        <value id="googletagmanager-com" type="host">*.googletagmanager.com</value>
        <value id="doubleclick-net" type="host">*.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="google-com" type="host">*.google.com</value>
        <value id="googlesyndication" type="host">*.googlesyndication.com</value>
        <value id="googletagservices" type="host">*.googletagservices.com</value>
        <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
        <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="script-src">
      <values>
        <value id="adobedtm" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
        <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
        <value id="google-ads" type="host">www.googleadservices.com</value>
        <value id="google-analytics" type="host">www.google-analytics.com</value>
        <value id="doubleclick" type="host">googleads.g.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="analytics-google" type="host">analytics.google.com</value>
        <value id="googletagmanager" type="host">www.googletagmanager.com</value>
        <value id="newrelic" type="host">*.newrelic.com</value>
        <value id="nr-data" type="host">*.nr-data.net</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce" type="host">geostag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-stag" type="host">1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-api" type="host">geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-api2" type="host">1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-songbird" type="host">songbird.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="ccdc02" type="host">includestest.ccdc02.com</value>
        <value id="paypal" type="host">www.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-sandbox" type="host">www.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-objects" type="host">www.paypalobjects.com</value>
        <value id="t-paypal" type="host">t.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="s-youtube" type="host">s.ytimg.com</value>
        <value id="googleapis" type="host">www.googleapis.com</value>
        <value id="vimeo" type="host">vimeo.com</value>
        <value id="vimeo-www" type="host">www.vimeo.com</value>
        <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
        <value id="youtube" type="host">*.youtube.com</value>
        <value id="gstatic" type="host">https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/</value>
        <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
        <value id="adyen" type="host">*.adyen.com</value>
        <value id="freshworks" type="host">widget.freshworks.com</value>
        <value id="freshdesk" type="host">m2epro.freshdesk.com</value>
        <value id="klarna" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
        <value id="klarnacdn" type="host">*.klarnacdn.net</value>
        <value id="klarnaservices" type="host">*.klarnaservices.com</value>
        <value id="avada" type="host">*.avada.io</value>
        <value id="google-analytics2" type="host">https://www.google-analytics.com</value>
        <value id="bing" type="host">https://bat.bing.com</value>
        <value id="google-de" type="host">www.google.de</value>
        <value id="googletagmanager-com" type="host">*.googletagmanager.com</value>
        <value id="doubleclick-net" type="host">*.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="googlesyndication" type="host">*.googlesyndication.com</value>
        <value id="googletagservices" type="host">*.googletagservices.com</value>
        <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
        <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-eval" type="host">'unsafe-eval'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="style-src">
      <values>
        <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
        <value id="freshworks" type="host">widget.freshworks.com</value>
        <value id="freshdesk" type="host">m2epro.freshdesk.com</value>
        <value id="klarnacdn" type="host">*.klarnacdn.net</value>
        <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
        <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
        <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="object-src">
      <values>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="media-src">
      <values>
        <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="manifest-src">
      <values>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="connect-src">
      <values>
        <value id="demdex" type="host">dpm.demdex.net</value>
        <value id="omtrdc" type="host">amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net</value>
        <value id="google-analytics" type="host">www.google-analytics.com</value>
        <value id="google-ads" type="host">www.googleadservices.com</value>
        <value id="analytics-google" type="host">analytics.google.com</value>
        <value id="googletagmanager" type="host">www.googletagmanager.com</value>
        <value id="newrelic" type="host">*.newrelic.com</value>
        <value id="nr-data" type="host">*.nr-data.net</value>
        <value id="vimeo" type="host">vimeo.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce" type="host">geostag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-geo" type="host">geo.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-stag" type="host">1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-api" type="host">1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-centinel" type="host">centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="cardinalcommerce-centinelapi" type="host">centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-sandbox" type="host">www.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="paypal-objects" type="host">www.paypalobjects.com</value>
        <value id="paypal" type="host">www.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="payflow" type="host">pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com</value>
        <value id="adyen" type="host">*.adyen.com</value>
        <value id="freshworks" type="host">widget.freshworks.com</value>
        <value id="freshdesk" type="host">m2epro.freshdesk.com</value>
        <value id="klarnaevt" type="host">*.klarnaevt.com</value>
        <value id="klarnacdn" type="host">*.klarnacdn.net</value>
        <value id="klarna" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
        <value id="klarnaservices" type="host">*.klarnaservices.com</value>
        <value id="geojs" type="host">https://get.geojs.io</value>
        <value id="avada" type="host">*.avada.io</value>
        <value id="doubleclick" type="host">*.doubleclick.net</value>
        <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
        <value id="googlesyndication" type="host">*.googlesyndication.com</value>
        <value id="googletagservices" type="host">*.googletagservices.com</value>
        <value id="google-analytics2" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="child-src">
      <values>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
        <value id="http" type="host">http:</value>
        <value id="https" type="host">https:</value>
        <value id="blob" type="host">blob:</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="default-src">
      <values>
        <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-eval" type="host">'unsafe-eval'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
    <policy id="base-uri">
      <values>
        <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
        <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
      </values>
    </policy>
  </policies>
</csp_whitelist>

As you can see I have collected a lot of entries yet.
Now there are still two problems which let me in a confused state.

I mainly use Brave to browse and within the developer console I dont
see any violations.

Inspecting the site in safari still shows many errors.



Now I wonder if there is something crucial I have missed or is it normal that there are still some errors remaining in the developer console ?

are you checking in developer mode or in production mode ? And also if you change or add anything on policy XML file then you need to re-deploy setup and remove static files.

In my local environment its developer mode and in staging env its production. Besides clearing cache I also do s:static-content:deploy -f and s:di:compile. I think the error is most likely that I do not report the violations to any url

If you are going to use CSP in report only mode, then you need to configure a Report URI in the admin panel or within config.xml: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/#report-uri-configuration
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_uri>http://csp-reporting-service.com/my-project/endpoint</report_uri>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_uri>http://csp-reporting-service.com/my-project/endpoint</report_uri>
                </admin>
            </mode>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>

If instead you want it to block any scripts that have not been added to your CSP whitelist, you would need to change the configuration to use restrict mode: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/#configure-a-modules-csp-mode
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_only>0</report_only>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_only>0</report_only>
                </admin>
            </mode>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>



You can follow the below steps to troubleshoot.

Verify csp_whitelist.xml Configuration
-> Try to check if all the errors you have covered in the file. Try removing self and unsafe-inline lines.

Clear Cache

Check CSP Headers

Verify Safari's CSP Errors

Debugging and Adjustments

Test Across Different Browsers


